# animation gets halted due to interrupt call in assembly

Tags: animation, assembly, timer, interrupt

in assembly, i am trying to do a animation. In the below code, move_object animates an object, while move_arrow animates another object. however, the problem is both uses the same timer function ( which i actually didn't understand how works, I just copied it from a source.) both runs finely in norma case. but what i want to do is that the object will keep animating from the start but the arrow will wait for user to press a specific key. when user presses that key, then the arrow will start. but whenever i call the interrupt function for keyboard press (MOV AH,0      INT 16H) the program gets halted there and waits for the user to press a key. but i want to have the previous to object to still move in that time. but no matter however i write the code it seems like the code gets halted in that line and no other lines get executed. below is the fragment of my code.

```
 ; dont know how it works , just know that it works as a timer :D
 TIMER_TICK PROC
    PUSH DS                ; SAVE DS
    PUSH AX
    MOV AX,SEG TIMER_FLAG  ; GET SEGMENT OF FLAG
    MOV DS,AX              ; PUT IN DS
    MOV TIMER_FLAG,1       ; SET FLAG
; RESTORE REGISTER  
     POP AX
     POP DS
     IRET ; IT IS DIFFERENT FROM "RET". IF WE USE "IRET" THEN 
          ; IF WILL REMAIN 1 WHICH MEANS IT CAN BE INTERRUPT AGAIN
 TIMER_TICK ENDP

;; other codes
;WAIT FOR TIMER TICK BEFORE MOVING THE OBJECT 

   TT:

       CMP TIMER_FLAG,1  ; TIMER TICKED?
       JNE TT            ; NO , KEEP TESTING
       MOV TIMER_FLAG,0  ; YES, CLEAR FLAG 
       CMP LAP,1         ; CHECKS IF ARROW HAVE FINISHED CROSSING
       JE GAME
       CALL MOVE_OBJECT  ;animates the object to a new position
       CMP KEY,0
       JNE CONT 
       MOV AH,0
       INT 16H  ;**whole program gets halted here untill user presses a key**
       OR AL,AL
       JNE EXIT
       CMP AH,3BH
       JNE GAME
       MOV KEY,1
       CONT:


       ; CHECK FOR KEYBOARD
       CALL MOVE_ARROW   ;animates the object in a new position



  ; DELAY 1 TIMER CLICK

   TT2:

        CMP TIMER_FLAG,1  ; TIMER TICKED?
        JNE TT2           ; NO , KEEP TESTING
        MOV TIMER_FLAG,0  ; YES , CLEAR FLAG
        JMP TT            ; GO GET NEXT OBJECT POSITION 
;; other codes
```

Answer (score 0):

The BIOS function you're using does indeed halt until a key is available from the keyboard. It's meant to work like that.
Consider using function 1 instead. That one will return immediately and report through the zero flag ZF if a key is waiting. So if ZF=1 you would probably jump back to TT.

```
mov ah,1
int 16h
jz TT
mov ah,0
int 16h
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the function ah=1 in int 16h. If a key was pressed until the moment, when the function ah=1 was called, the ZF is set and AX contains the values that would be set, if you had used ah=0. Otherwise, if no key had been pressed, the ZF is not set and AX won't contain a useful value. Notice: If you use the function ah=1, you have to use function ah=0 if a key had been pressed, cause the keybuffer wouldn't be changed otherwise.